# Не работает Windows проверка подлинности и Sql проверка подлинности одновременно

Tags: sql-server

[image: Подключение через Sql]

[image: через Админа]

[image: Сервер есть а зарегистрированных]

[image: Все службы запущены]

Прочитал уже кучу форумов, так и не нашел решение

Имя сервера: 
Номер ошибки: 18456
Серьезность: 14
Состояние: 1

Comment: Ничего нельзя сделать. Проверка подлинности windows - означает, что текущему пользователю windows должно быть в mssql разрешено шастать. То что пользователь администратор - никого не волнует, надо что б в таблице пользователь был внесен тот пользователь, под которым заходите.

Comment: @teran да, нужно проверить разрешены ли удаленные подключения. Ошибка 18465 http://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/error-sql-server-error-starting-esri_sde-service-93-dbms-error-code-18456/

Comment: я пробовал через всех пользователей, везде одна и та же ошибка

Comment: Вот на русском http://wiki.merionet.ru/servernye-resheniya/12/reshaem-error-18456-v-sql/

Comment: @nick_n_a, не работает эта инструкция, я не зря скинул скриншот от администратора, ибо перепробовал всех пользователей, а в этой инструкции говориться, что от админа можно войти, как и во многих других, но у меня не получается войти

Comment: Пробуйте подключаться локально. Может там запрещены удалённые подключения. Проблему можно решить, только если есть доступ к mssql локально под админской учёткой. Если никакого доступа нету - путь один - переустановка сервера.

Comment: Что именно не работает? Подключайтесь локально под sa (если он разрешён и пароль известен). Судя по картинкам - вы подключаетесь не локально.

Comment: локально нет возможности, сервер за пару тысяч км, переустановка не помогает, пробовал уже

Comment: Если ничего не выходит - тогда переустанавливайте mssql, в процессе установки разрешите sa и дайте ему пароль который сможете повторить. Не понимаю как *переустановка не помогает* получилось, а *локально нет возможности* ? Заходите туда например по RDP или по team viewer и настраивайте.

Comment: @nick_n_a на скрине написано вроде, что это локальный сервер "группа локальных серверов"

Comment: @teran, написано, ибо нахожусь на удаленной машине через рдп

Comment: ну дак значит подключение локальное. sa пароль точно корректный?

Comment: @nick_n_a, хорошо, может я в процессе переустановки неправльный пароль на sa указал

Comment: если есть возможность перезапуска сервера, то рестартните его в монопольном режиме и подключитесь как админ. настройте права и замените пароли как надо. в монопольном он пустит админа компа, емнип. не надо переустанавливать ничего

Comment: @teran, пробовал, ошибку выбивает

Comment: *группа локальных серверов* - ничего не значит, имя сервера в верхнем закрашеном чёрном окне.  Вот в первое окошко можно localhost вписать - будет тогда понятно что локально подключаетесь.

Comment: ну дак напишите про это в вопросе-то. чего вы частично сведения даете?

Comment: @nick_n_a Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login failed for user '******\Администратор'    При подключении в однопользовательском режиме

Comment: Это попытка подключиться  с правами администратора пользователем MyCoolHomePC\Администратор к удаленному серверу? Хм... действительно очень странно, что не пускает

Comment: всем спасибо, разобрался благодаря этой статье https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Endvile может основное из статьи опубликовать в виде ответа, чтоб другими помогло)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica там и так все понятно)

Comment: @Endvile для вас да. Но у нас тут, всё же, база знаний, призванная помочь людям. Если вы основное из статьи по ссылке перенесёте в ответ, то людям, столкнувшимся с этой же проблемой, будет куда проще.